# primeng floatlabel issue with textarea

Tags: angular, textarea, primeng

I'm stuck to below issue related to primeng textarea and float labels:

[image: on load element]

only after i click at every point of the page I got expected result:

[image: after click]

other elements like dropodowns and input fields are properly rendered in same page with float labels, below is my code:

```html
//.html file
<span class="p-float-label">
    <textarea inputId="description" rows="3" style="resize: none;" cols="40" [(ngModel)]="sampleData"
        pInputTextarea [readOnly]="false"></textarea>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
</span>
```

```js
// .ts component file 
sampleData : string = "big issue";
```

Can anyone assist?
Thanks

Edit:

A workaround using a .markforcheck() call fix the issue but triggers the animation which moves the label from inside to outside.
The goal is to have the label properly displayed at start.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo?  It looks ok when I tried with latest version

Comment: What version of primeng are you using right now ?

Comment: primeng version is 11.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3955

Issue still exists but there is a solution, in your case you can use this code and it will work just fine for floatLabel textareas when using placeholder

```css
textarea:focus ~ label,
textarea ~ label {
  top: -.75em!important;
  font-size: 12px!important;
}
```